# Calculate hash over a whole column from pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a big data frame (approximatively 40 million rows) which looks like this:

```
|col A | col B |
|------|-------|
|valA1 | valB1 |
|valA2 | valB2 |
```

I want to compare two column in different data frames, in different workspaces. I am not allowed to bring both of them to the same environment. What I want is creating a hash value for every column, so I can compare with other columns from the other data frame.

The easy approach would be concatenating all values from a column, and then hash the resulting string. But because of the size of the data frame, I cannot do this.

So far I tried this version, but it takes too long:

```
hashlib.sha256(''.join(map(str,df.agg(collect_list(col("colName"))).first()[0])).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

and also this but same long time:

```
def compute_hash(df):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    dataCollect=df.rdd.toLocalIterator()
    for row in dataCollect:
        hasher.update(row['colName'].encode('utf-8'))
    return hasher.hexdigest()
```

Is this achievable in spark in a reasonable time?

Comment: yes it is achievable

Comment: Could you show some code of what have you been trying?

Comment: Done. Maybe I am not looping correctly through the data frame

Comment: It seems like rdd comes with a hugh performance cost: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was grouping by a column which contained data evenly distributed. This way, spark would trigger the parallel execution for every value from the "columnToGroupBy" and generate a dataframe containing on the first column all the values of "columnToGroupBy" and on the second column, a hash over the concatenated values of "colToHash" corresponding to that value of "columnToGroupBy". For example if we had this table:

| columnToGroupBy | colToHash |
| --- | --- |
| ValueA1 | ValB1 |
| ValueA2 | ValB2 |
| ValueA1 | ValB3 |
| ValueA2 | ValB4 |

After aplying this function:

```
df.groupby("columnToGroupBy").agg(md5(concat_ws(",", array_sort(collect_set(col("colToHash"))))))
```

We would get the following dataframe:

| columnToGroupBy | hash |
| --- | --- |
| ValueA1 | md5(ValB1 |
| ValueA2 | md5(ValB1 |

If you have this new dataframe with a small number of rows, equal to the number of values you have in "columnToGroupBy", you can easily generate a hash for the whole column by collecting all the values from the "hash" column, concatenating them and hashing over.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to hash the whole string at once.

Example using `sha256` from `hashlib`s library

```py
import hashlib

column = ['valA1', 'valA2', 'valA3']

hasher = hashlib.sha256()

for row in column:
    hasher.update(row.encode('utf-8'))

print(hasher.hexdigest())
# >>> 68f900960718b4881107929da0918e0e9f50599b12ebed3ec70066e55c3ec5f4
```

Using the `update` method will process the data as you use it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but I already tried this and it takes too long. Even just looping through the column values takes about half an hour.

Comment: How many items do you have?

Comment: about 40 milions

Comment: What is the average length of the items?

Comment: it's 32 characters each